# PHP SQL query error message

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on a tutorial and copied the code below exactly but I'm getting the following error message. Any ideas what's wrong with the syntax?

> Database query failed: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'BY position ASC' at line 2

```
function get_pages_for_subject($subject_id, $public = true) {
            global $connection;
            $query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE subject_id = .$subject_id.";
            if ($public) {
                $query .= "AND visible = 1 ";
            }
            $query .= "ORDER BY position ASC";
            $page_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($page_set);
            return $page_set;
            }
```

Comment: Please show the full generated query. Chances are `$subject_id` is not a number and needs to be wrapped in quotes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm a newbie working on a tutorial so a lot is unclear to me. However, I believe you suggested the same thing (wrapping in quotes) as someone below, a tip I followed that unfortunately didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could have abstracted the PHP out of this, probably.

Printing `$query` will show you that `$subject_id` is probably not what you think it is.
Also, where is your SQL Injection prevention?

Comment: I'm just working on a tutorial to learn this stuff. It's not teaching SQL injection at this time...but good to note. thanks

Comment: @Michael: So, did you print `$query` to see what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Please enforce that `$subject_id` is an integer value or wrap it out with quotes:

```
$subject_id = (int)$subject_id; before your $query .= "WHERE subject_id = {$subject_id} ";
```

or

```
$query .= "WHERE subject_id = '{$subject_id}' ";
```

This should work. The issue is that `$subject_id` value is breaking out your query.

Small advice: Enforce some security here, you should prevent SQL injection scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You should backquote all your field names. like

```
`visible` = 1

ORDER BY `position`
```

And so on, to be sure nothing conflicts with a reserved MySQL word (I'm thinking about "position" which is a string function).